# Function Works in Excel Macro But Does not Work in VB.Net

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I rephrased the question with full details here:

I have an Industrial code with function which works in VBA and I am trying to convert it to VB.net as per our management decision.

Here is the Code and Function Code which are working in VBA

Code

```
    Sub CutEm()
    Dim rOut As Range
    Dim avInp As Variant
    Dim dKerf As Double
    Dim dStk As Double
    Dim iOut As Long
    Dim nOut As Long
    dKerf = Range("ptrKerf").Value2
    dStk = Range("ptrStk").Value2
    With Range("rgnInp")
        If WorksheetFunction.Max(.Columns(1).Value) > dStk Then
            MsgBox "Piece length cannot exceed stock length", _
                   Buttons:=vbOKOnly, _
                   Title:="shg Cut List"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        avInp = .Value
        iOut = .Column + 3
        Set rOut = .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, iOut).Resize(.Rows.count)
    End With
    rOut.Resize(, Columns.count - iOut + 1).EntireColumn.Clear
    rOut(1, 0).Resize(Rows.count - rOut.Row).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    **With WorksheetFunction
        Do While .Sum(.Index(avInp, 0, 2))
            nOut = nOut + 1
            rOut.Columns(nOut) = .Transpose(aiCut(avInp, dKerf, dStk)) 'Function
        Loop
    End With**
    Set rOut = rOut.Resize(, nOut)
    With rOut
        .Style = "Input"
        .NumberFormat = "General_);;"
             With .Rows(-1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=column() - " & .Column - 1
            .Value = .Value
            .Style = "Input"
        End With
        With .Rows(0)
       .FormulaR1C1 = "=max(0, ptrStk - sumproduct(r[1]c:r[" & 
       rOut.Rows.count & "]c, rgnLen + ptrKerf))"
            .Style = "Formula"
            .NumberFormat = "0.0"
        End With
        .Columns(0).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(rc[1]:rc[" & nOut & "])"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Worksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = .Address
     End With
```

Here is the Function:

```
    Function aiCut(avInp As Variant, dKerf As Double, dStk As Double) As Long()
        Dim col As New Collection
        Dim nInp, iInp, aiQty(), aiMin() As Long
        Dim dRem, dRemMin As Double
        nInp = UBound(avInp)
        dRemMin = dStk
        ReDim aiQty(1 To nInp)    
        With col
            iInp = 1
            dRem = dStk
            Do
                Do While avInp(iInp, 1) > dRem Or avInp(iInp, 2) <= 0
                    iInp = iInp + 1
                    If iInp > nInp Then
                        If dRem < dRemMin Then
                            dRemMin = dRem
                            aiMin = aiQty
                            If dRemMin < 0.001 * dStk Then GoTo Outtahere
                        End If
                        If .Count = 1 Then
                            GoTo Outtahere
                        Else
                            iInp = .Item(.Count)
                            If iInp >= nInp Then
                                GoTo Outtahere
                            Else
                                dRem = dRem + avInp(iInp, 1) + dKerf
                                avInp(iInp, 2) = avInp(iInp, 2) + 1
                                aiQty(iInp) = aiQty(iInp) - 1
                                iInp = iInp + 1
                                .Remove(.Count)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop
                .Add(Item:=iInp)
                avInp(iInp, 2) = avInp(iInp, 2) - 1
                aiQty(iInp) = aiQty(iInp) + 1
                dRem = dRem - avInp(iInp, 1) - dKerf
            Loop
        End With
Outtahere:
        aiCut = aiMin   
        For iInp = 1 To nInp
            avInp(iInp, 2) = avInp(iInp, 2) + aiQty(iInp) - aiMin(iInp)
        Next iInp
    End Function
```

VB.net problems:
1- Variant Data type has no equivalent except Object which sometimes does not work as Variant.
2- Syntax `Redim aiQty(1 to nInp)` does not accept 1 but 0 because of
`UBound(avInp)` in the Function.

Hope that the question is clear and appreciate your help

Thanks, Regards

Comment: Start by changing it to `ReDim aiQty(nInp)` and then also change `iInp = 0` so that the loop starts at 0 instead of 1. However, you are passing `avInp` and not telling us anything about it, so there will be much more that will need to be changed that no one here is going to be able to do for you. There could be other ways to fix it, but as it stands, there is not enough information here to give you a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks your reply and I will test it, However I am not hiding anything, actually I borrowed this code from the web in order to do special function and I do not understand the code exactly as I should but I just in need of it. Thanks your understanding, Regards.

Comment: Here: `Function aiCut(avInp As Object,` you are passing an `Object` which is most likely an array, but without being able to know anything about that `Object`, very little can be done to help.

Comment: @ braX , I put Object instead of Variant since the VB Does not recognize Variant, it is Variant type

Comment: Yes, i know. However that makes no difference. Neither tells us anything about what is being passed.

Comment: Please note that if you `Dim dRem, dRemMin As Double` in VBA only `dRemMin` is of type `Double` but `dRem` is of type `Variant`. While in VB.NET `Dim dRem, dRemMin As Double` declares both variables as type `Double` in VBA you need do specify a type for **every** variable `Dim dRem As Double, dRemMin As Double` or it is `Variant` by default. In most cases VBA code cannot be copied to VB.NET and it needs a re-write or at least a decent check. These are 2 different languages and handle many things differently.

Comment: If you change `aiQty(1 To nInp)` to `aiQty(0 To nInp)` then you need to change `aiQty(iInp)` to `aiQty(iInp - 1)` too, or otherwise counting is wrong.

Comment: I would advise you to get rid of this array, non-generic-collection and GoTo nonsense and write proper VB .NET code.

Comment: @Mimi2020: so you're saying you don't know what data type `avInp` actually is in the original code? Can you give us at least an oral description of what this code is supposed to do? Other than that, I'd get rid off the `Object` code variant and instead go with `Overloads` methods for the respective data type.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Since you are calling UBound on avInp, it has to be an array. BTW, Array.GetUpperBound(Int32)  is the .net replacement for the vb6 UBound.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling UBound on avInp, it has to be an array. I noticed further down that your are referring to 2 indexes so it must be a 2 dimensional array. Since you are comparing the values in the array to Doubles I assigned the type Double.

```
Function aiCut(avInp(,) As Double, dKerf As Double, dStk As Double) As Long()
```

We don't use Collection as a type in vb.net new code

```
Dim col As New List(Of Long)
```

You can't declare an array with a Long. It's UpperBound must be an Integer (Int32)

BTW, Array.GetUpperBound(Int32) is the .net replacement for the vb6 UBound.

```
nInp = avInp.GetUpperBound(1)
```

At least all of the red squiggles are gone so it should compile. I have no idea if it will do what you want.
That last for loop doesn't seem to accomplish anything.

In general vb.net arrays start at index 0. They are declared `MyArray(UBound) As Integer`

```
Function aiCut(avInp(,) As Double, dKerf As Double, dStk As Double) As Long()
    Dim col As New List(Of Long)
    Dim nInp As Integer
    Dim iInp As Integer
    Dim aiQty(), aiMin() As Long
    Dim dRem, dRemMin As Double
    nInp = avInp.GetUpperBound(1)
    dRemMin = dStk
    ReDim aiQty(nInp)
    With col
        iInp = 1
        dRem = dStk
        Dim Done = False
        Do
            Do While avInp(iInp, 1) > dRem Or avInp(iInp, 2) <= 0
                iInp += 1
                If iInp > nInp Then
                    If dRem < dRemMin Then
                        dRemMin = dRem
                        aiMin = aiQty
                        If dRemMin < 0.001 * dStk Then 'GoTo Outtahere
                            Done = True
                            Exit Do
                        End If

                        If .Count = 1 Then 'GoTo Outtahere
                            Done = True
                            Exit Do
                        End If

                    Else
                        iInp = .Count
                        If iInp >= nInp Then
                            'GoTo Outtahere
                            Done = True
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            dRem = dRem + avInp(iInp, 1) + dKerf
                            avInp(iInp, 2) = avInp(iInp, 2) + 1
                            aiQty(iInp) = aiQty(iInp) - 1
                            iInp = iInp + 1
                            .Remove(.Count)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Loop
            If Done Then Exit Do
            .Add(iInp)
            avInp(iInp, 2) = avInp(iInp, 2) - 1
            aiQty(iInp) = aiQty(iInp) + 1
            dRem = dRem - avInp(iInp, 1) - dKerf
        Loop
    End With
    'Outtahere:
    aiCut = aiMin
    For iInp = 0 To nInp - 1
        avInp(iInp, 2) = avInp(iInp, 2) + aiQty(iInp) - aiMin(iInp)
    Next iInp
    Return aiMin
End Function
```

Comment: @ Mary, I would like to thank you for your support, However the avInp should be of type Variant in VBA Or Equivalent Object in VB, So I changed only this line of code as you suggested `nInp = avInp.GetUpperBound(1)` and I left the rest, I think it worked until the line `avInp(iInp, 2) = avInp(iInp, 2) + aiQty(iInp) - aiMin(iInp)` which gave an error: Index was outside the bounds of the array?

Comment: @ Mary, Actually this function is part of another code which uses the function in the following line : `With xl.WorksheetFunction`-`Do While .Sum(.Index(avInp, 0, 2))`
                        `rOut.Columns(nOut) = .Transpose(aiCut(avInp, dKerf, dStk))`
                        `Loop`
        End With`

Comment: @ Mary, If you want to see the whole code , no problem, I just need to fix the function syntax, Thanks

Comment: @Mimi2020 It would be wise if you try to contact the author of the VB6 code and let him explain what the code is supposed to do...

Comment: Dear All, I edited the question above with full details, thanks

Comment: @ Mary, you have the full code, could you please help converting to vb.net, thanks

Comment: @ Mary, I Changed Variant Type to Object Type and I receive Error "Index was outside the bounds of the Array at the Code Line `dRem = dRem + avInp(iInp, 1) + dKerf`, Thanks

Comment: Find out the value of the upper bound of the first index in the array. Then check if iInp is equal to or les than the upper bound. BTW, be sure Option Strict is turned of for the project.

Comment: @ Mary, how I find the upper bound of the first index in the array?, Thanks

Comment: `Dim a = arr.GetUpperBound(1)` Where 1 refers to the dimension of the array. This bit of code will get the upper bound of the first dimension.

Comment: @ Mary, VB Does not accept arr.GetUpperBound(1) or Array.GetUpperBound(1), Thanks

Comment: @Mimi2020 You are correct. It should be `Dim a = arr.GetUpperBound(0)` to get the upper bound of the first dimension.